# ntpdate shows offset but does not synchronize

Tags: centos, ntp, ntpd

I am trying to time-synchronize 2 Centos VM with ntpdate command, but it won't work.

When running the ntpdate command (`ntpdate reference.time.machine`), it shows an offset : step time server 10.0.0.116 offset 156.479697 sec

But when I run the "date" command, it still shows the time with no correction.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Sylvain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the issue :

I edited the file /etc/sysconfig/ntpd to add the following line :

```
SYNC_HWCLOCK=yes
```

Since then, it seems to work.

Sylvain.